# Make dataframe rows as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like :

```
 country  indicator y1  y2    y3   y4
0   abc    a       0.1  0.1   0.1   0.1
1   abc    b       0.1  0.2   0.4   0.1
2   wed    a       0.1  0.1   0.1   0.1
3   wed    b       0.7  0.1   0.6   0.1
```

I need something like:

```
 country    y         a    b
0   abc    y1       0.1  0.1
           y2       0.1  0.2 
           y3       0.1  0.1  
           y4       0.7  0.1  
1   wed    y1       0.1  0.1
           y2       0.1  0.2 
           y3       0.1  0.1  
           y4       0.7  0.1
```

The solutions point to transpose but i can't seem to convert them exactly as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.set_index(['country','indicator']).stack().unstack(1)
```

Output:

```
indicator     a    b
country             
abc     y1  0.1  0.1
        y2  0.1  0.2
        y3  0.1  0.4
        y4  0.1  0.1
wed     y1  0.1  0.7
        y2  0.1  0.1
        y3  0.1  0.6
        y4  0.1  0.1
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. Another question would be that I have multiple indicators i.e. a,b,c,d,e.. but require only two indicators a,b . Is there a way to set index for suppose only indicator a,b?